# Can't upvote comments on meta math se in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

When I select a comment on Math SE in the Android app, I am able to upvote it. When I select a comment on Math SE meta, it only shows me user profile, copy text, and share. This is new behavior; I was always able to upvote meta comments before.

I know the android app is no longer under development, but I wish it would be because it is superior than trying to use a browser to access SE sites on an android device.

[image]

Comment: I’ve been logged out of all meta sites on the iOS app and had to reconnect. If you try to (for example) upvote a post does it go through?

Comment: @Laurel Yes, I can upvote a meta post.

Comment: I was about to post a bug report about Meta sites in the iOS app suddenly telling me that I am not a member of the site. Seems like this might be the same thing.

Comment: @Alex Maybe related, but the "Add comment" button is present, and it isn't present when I'm not a member or not logged into the site.

Comment: `... it is superior than trying to use a browser to access SE sites on an android device.` - Have you tried Firefox (or even Chrome) for Android. Here is what Firefox looks like in [Desktop Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKMkS.jpg) and [Mobile Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nKO1.jpg) - I prefer the desktop version, either way everything works; or you ***can*** file a Bug Report. I think altering the website to accommodate the unsupported APP is unlikely, but you *are* welcome to ask.

Comment: This happens on MSO as well.

Comment: @Rob even with a home screen shortcut, it's just not as convenient. The website has to load each page, instead of just the data; the layout isn't consistent across the different sites; a few pages still aren't responsive... There's more I'm forgetting. Even though the apps are breaking down, I still find them easier to use.

Comment: @Rob Posting pictures doesn't work on the app, so I had to use the site with Chrome. One of the links took over 30 seconds to load. I felt like throwing my phone out the window. For some reason there's never a lag in the app.

Comment: Matt, I have slow Internet and a 2 year old phone. Both images in my comment, or this entire webpage load and render almost instantly. I respect your right to ask for this to be fixed, I am only explaining that previous requests to  accommodate the APP have been denied; and people have been told to install FF or Chrome for Android/iOS. --- I wouldn't want you to wait a week to hear: "No".